# Regex, php : how to negate a capturing parentheses

Tags: php, regex

I want to analyse a mysql request with a php regex,
that is, extract the select_expr and the table_references from a mysql statement.
For example, here are two mysql queries that I would like my regex to match :

```
select id, name from table

select id, name
```

From that query I would like to extract 2 parts : the "id, name" information and the "table" information too.

The first part can actually contain a string like CONCAT('id','.','nom') AS alias,

and the second part can look like : table t INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t.id=t2.user_id.

So I tried this "I know it's not working but will get me on the road" regex :

```
'!select (.*)( from (.*))?!i'
```

And of course, the first capturing parentheses get all until the end, which is not what I want.

In the

```
select id, name from table
```

string, it matches "id, nom from table" as the first part, which is not what I want.
(I want "id, nom" as the first part and "table" as the second in this case).

What I would like to do from this point is to tell the regex that the first capturing parentheses
should not match the " from " sequence if founded.
I know there is the negated character class feature, [^a-z],
but that just negate one character and not a whole string (as a sequence of letters in the right order).

Do you have any lights on this ?
Can we negate the content of parentheses for example with regex ?

Comment: Does '!^select (.*?)(?: from (.*))?$!i'  work?

Comment: Oh yes it does, thank you, I will investigate that (?:) notation. really kool.

Answer (score 1):

The last bit if your question makes it sound like the 'from' part of your query is optional, is that right?

If so, then try this:

```
!^select (.*?)(?: from (.*))?$!i
```

This will match everything between "select" and "from", if "from" is found, otherwise it will just match everything after "select".

By adding the ? in ".*?" it tells the '*' to not be greedy, so when it hits a place where the rest of the expression matches, it won't keep taking more characters.
I also added the '?:', which makes the second group a non-capturing group, since there is no useful info to read from it. Finally wrap the expression in ^ and $ to mark line start and end.

If 'from' is NOT optional though, then it is a lot easier and you can just use this:

```
!^select (.*) from (.*)$!i
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use [greedy matching](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html#12). That is, your first `.*` group matches characters until the rest of your regex breaks. Since the `FROM` clause is made optional, it never happens and your first group just matches everything. The solution is to use non-greedy matching, by adding a `?` after the `*` (it also works for `+`).

```
'!select (.*?)( from (.*))?!i'
```

It should be enough for your simple case. If you want to parse a whole query, though, it's actually much, much easier to parse SQL statements backwards. For instance, let's have a fully-featured SQL query:

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE cond GROUP BY col HAVING stuff ORDER BY this
```

If you [`strrev`](http://ca.php.net/manual/fr/function.strrev.php) it, you get:

```
siht YB REDRO ffuts GNIVAH loc YB PUORG dnoc EREHW rab MORF oof TCELES
```

With that in mind, you can easily split it with a regex, without ending with a LISPesque amount of stacked parentheses. Here's a commented regex I made to match such a string (you would need to put it back on a single line with no whitespaces).

```
^ // match the beginning
    (.+\s+YB\s*REDRO)?\s* // is there an ORDER BY?
    (.+\s+GNIVAH)?\s* // is there a HAVING?
    (.+\s+YB\s*PUORG)?\s* // is there a GROUP BY?
    (.+\s+EREHW)?\s* // is there a WHERE?
    (.+\s+MORF)?\s* // is there a FROM?
    .+\s+TCELES // there is a SELECT
$ // match the end
```

Now, all you have to do is `strrev` back your results, and voilà! you got a well-split query.

**EDIT** We can use non-capturing groups and named groups to enhance the regex. Right now, we get the individual clauses through the matches; that is, they start with a keyword. Without the keyword, it would get pretty confusing to tell what's what in the capture groups. Named groups help solve this problem.

Non-capturing groups are groups that don't appear in the regex results. They start with `?:`, and they're useful to make a block optional (like `(?:stuff here)?`) without having to deal with it in the results.

Here's the new regex. I've also just [learned about the `x` modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) which makes PCRE ignore whitespaces and accept comments inside regexes, so let's use that to make a valid snippet.

```
$regex = "/^
    (?:(?<orderby>.+)\s+YB\s*REDRO)?\s* # is there an ORDER BY?
    (?:(?<having>.+)\s+GNIVAH)?\s*      # is there a HAVING?
    (?:(?<groupby>.+)\s+YB\s*PUORG)?\s* # is there a GROUP BY?
    (?:(?<where>.+)\s+EREHW)?\s*        # is there a WHERE?
    (?:(?<from>.+)\s+MORF)?\s*          # is there a FROM?
    (?<select>.+)\s+TCELES              # there is a SELECT
$/msix";

$query = "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE cond GROUP BY col HAVING stuff ORDER BY this";

preg_match($regex, strrev($query), $matches);
foreach ($matches as &$match)
    $match = strrev($match);

// now we can use $matches['from'] to get the FROM clause
echo $matches['from'];

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: very tricky, but it may fail when the user tries to select a MORFEUS field for example ;(

Comment: @ling, you're right. `\s*` matches zero or more whitespaces, and we want one or more. I'll change it to `\s+`, which matches one or more whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$string = "select id, name, CONCAT('id','.','nom') AS alias as a from table t INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t.id=t2.user_id";
preg_match_all("!select (.*) from (.*)!i", $string, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

I just tested it and it works just fine.

Comment: It doesn't work on `select id, name` alone, which is the second example of query that OP wants to parse.